# Should an exclamation point be added after an "autocmd" in a filetypedetect augroup?

Tags: autocmd, filetype

I'm trying to learn more about [augroups](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html), which have always confused me. The Section 43.2 documentation (`:help 43.2`) makes it clear that the *filetypedetect* group should be used to group autocmds which set filetypes, as grouping them in this way allows the autocmds to be turned on and off collectively.

However, I am not clear about one minor detail: should `autocmd` or `autocmd!` be used in the *filetypedetect* augroup? I understand how they differ, but it seems the documentation offers contradictory recommendations. Section 43.2 (`:help 43.2`) shows a *filetypedetect* augroup which uses `autocmd` while part C of the `new-filetype` documentation (`:help new-filetype`) shows a *filetypedetect* augroup which uses `autocmd!`.

Should `autocmd` or `autocmd!` be used in *filetypedetect* augroups?

Comment: IIRC autocommands put in ftdetect scripts are automatically put in a group

Comment: That's true but `filetypedetect` groups are unrelated to the `ftdetect` directories. They are part of an alternative approach to detection. (There are a total of four approaches.)

Comment: You made a damn fine point @John (though I should have thought of it myself) and my answer would have to change to doing `au!` everywhere but filetypedetect in which case you'd use `au! Events ...etc`. I'd rather nuke an answer than give a wishy washy one. :)